# My executeUpdate() working, but not commit

Tags: java, postgresql, jboss, datasource

I'm trying to insert data in my postgresql database, but, when I execute the executeUpdate() method, it doesn't insert any data on my DB, and I cannot see where I'm doing wrong...

Ps: My database is autocommit: on;

I'm using Jboss 7.1.1 here my dataSource configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgresqlDS" pool-name="PostgreDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://dataBaseAddress/dataBaseName</connection-url>
                    <driver>org.postgresql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>user</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="org.postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

Here is my connection class:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws TopLevelException, SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
              Context ctx = new InitialContext();
              TransactionBean tal = (TransactionBean) ctx.lookup("java:global/snrng-ear/snrng-ejb-lgc/TransactionBean!br.com.compplied.snrng.ejb.TransactionBean");
              conn = tal.getConnection();
          } catch (NamingException e) {
              throw new TopLevelException(e);
          }
          return conn;
    }
```

Here is the method that execute my insert

```
public int inserirHistorico(RetornoHistoricoObject retorno) throws TopLevelException {
        int update = 0;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = null;
        String sql = "INSERT INTO table ( column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, localtimestamp)";
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.getResultSet();
            ps.setString(1, retorno.getNome_arquivo());
            ps.setString(2, retorno.getNumero_autenticacao().trim());
            ps.setString(3, retorno.getNosso_numero());
            ps.setDate(4, retorno.getData_pagamento());
            ps.setDouble(5, retorno.getValor());
            update = ps.executeUpdate();  

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new TopLevelException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new TopLevelException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                close(rs, ps, con);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new TopLevelException(e);
            }
        }
        return update;
    }
```

When I execute the ps.executeUpdate() method, is returned to me a success message with the new id inserted, but, when I look for this id on my table, there's nothing inserted there. I've already checked my DB parameter, connection and so, but it's still not working... Can anyone help me?

Comment: This probably isn't the cause of your problem, but why do you have a `ResultSet` and why are you calling `getResultSet()`?

Comment: @Samuel hi man, thanks, the resultSet is wrong, I removed it, bad still does not work :(

Comment: Why don't you look up the data source instead of your custom bean and get the connection from it?

Comment: Do you have the Transactional annotation on your classes/methods?

Comment: What happens if you call `commit()` on the connection? Maybe the connection you get has auto commit disabled. Btw. why are you using a XADataSource? And not a "regular" DataSource? The XA DataSource is for distribute transactions (between different application servers). Does using the `org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource` change anything?

Comment: Hi All, 
My problem was solved, I'm JTA = "true" found that when we use JTA he did not enter my data if any exception happens, then hung up the JTA solved my problem with the data bank and it worked :))))))))

Answer (score 0):

In order to isolate the problem, try:

1. Perform a manual insert in the DB to check the autocommit setting? If work - problem in Java. If do not work - problem in DB
2. Create a simple class to perform the insert and check if it works. It work, problem with app settings. If do not work - FU## something with Java/Driver!
3. If 1 and 2 work, try to use a Transaction:

   ```
   Transaction t =  beginTransaction(); // session???
   //your code here
   tx.commit;
   ```

Comment: welcome to SO! Please, take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to earn your first shiny badge.

Comment: Hi All, 
My problem was solved, I'm JTA = "true" found that when we use JTA he did not enter my data if any exception happens, then hung up the JTA solved my problem with the data bank and it worked :))))))))